# adb alias screenshot on Windows with Git bash not working

Tags: android, bash, adb

The final purpose is to obtain a screenshot of an android app (in development on Android Studio), running on a real device not in an AVD.

While trying to create a **.bashrc file** with the following code (just for testing):
`alias screenshot="adb exec-out screenshot -p > ~/Desktop/adb_screen.png"`,  I get an adb_screen.png file on my Desktop that is not recognized as an image (no dimensions), so I can`t open it.

Important to notice that the screenshot I am trying to take is from a real device connected. In fact, when I run `adb devices -l` it recognizes the device I want to take the screenshot from.
Could you help me solve this issue.
Thanks,

Comment: Inspecting the file is a good place to start. If `adb` writes anything to its stdout rather than passing through the parent process's output _exactly_, there's your problem.

Comment: BTW, I doubt (indeed, am in utter disbelief) that it being an alias has anything to do with it. Always try to simplify as much as possible when asking a question: If you get the same problem when you run `adb exec-out screenshot -p > ~/Desktop/adb_screen.png` at a git bash / msys-bash command line _without_ it being an alias, then you should ask the question that way without aliases being involved.

Comment: (If it _is_ alias-specific, then I would suspect that the generated filename has a hidden character on the end, as could happen if your `.bashrc` was saved with the wrong newline type; in any event, running `set -x` to enable trace logging before invoking the alias will show the command that's actually being run, to allow issues of that general sort to be run down).

Comment: Assuming that it happens only when you run adb from bash and not when you run adb from cmd.exe, by the way, it might be worth looking at whether the stream is going through processing intended for text -- the CR vs CRLF conflict is very real, and programs that try to translate binary data as if it were text can easily cause corruption.

Comment: But really -- _inspect the file_. See if it starts with some text that shouldn't be there. See how its actual size differs from the size of the same file if generated on the device without being transported over adb's stdout. Compare `hexdump` output of the original file and the broken version; etc. All these debugging steps are things you can do because you have the real hardware and the actual files, but that we _can't_ do ourselves from here.

Comment: @Alex Thanks so much for your inputs and advice. After checking the .bashrc file it was indeed a problem with this file. Now it's working. Next time I will be more careful before presenting a question.